# Get the Xcode project directory from the code

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Does anyone know how to get a related Xcode project directory right from the code? I've tried to accomplish it with the `pwd` environment, but it only works in `Build Phases` > `Run Script`.

Comment: Do you mean from the app code that you are debugging in Xcode?

Comment: @LouFranco yes, something like that: `print($SRCROOT)` :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for individual files you can either use the C-macro `__FILE__`, or the swift-literal `#file`.

[From the Swift Docs (search for `Literal Expressions` on the page)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html)

- `#file` (String) The name of the file in which it appears.
- `#line` (Int) The line number on which it appears.
- `#column` (Int) The column number in which it begins.
- `#function` (String) The name of the declaration in which it appears.

Once you have the path to the file it should be easy to find your way to the project root.